# Scan pivot table for two identical values

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

I have this pivot table:

```
+----+---------+-----------------+
| id | user_id | conversation_id |
+----+---------+-----------------+
| 1  | 2       | 48              |
+----+---------+-----------------+
| 2  | 1       | 48              |
+----+---------+-----------------+
```

I am trying to find a way to detect if two users are in the same conversation, and if they are, return the conversation. Someting like:

```
Conversation::with([1, 2]); // should return conversation 48
```

My `Conversation` class looks like this:

```
class Conversation extend Eloquent {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

    public function messages(){
        return $this->hasMany('Message');
    }
}
```

So far I have below code, but it is clumsy and very ineffective, and thought that there must exists some cleaner Laravel way:

```
class Conversation {

    public static function user_filter(Array $users) {

        $ids = array();

        foreach ($users as $user)
            $ids[$user->id] = $user->id;

        sort($ids);

        foreach (self::all() as $conversation){ // loop through ALL conversations (!!!)
            $u_ids = $conversation->users->lists('id');
            sort ( $u_ids );

            if ($u_ids === $ids)
                return $conversation;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Conversation::user_filter([User::find(1), User::find(2)]); // returns conversation 48
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first look at how you can actually retrieve the result without having too loop trough all kind of arrays...

You can use the [`whereHas`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations) function to filter a relationship. We can apply conditions and if they are met for the related records of a model, it will be included in the result.

```
$conversations = Conversation::whereHas('users', function($q){
    $q->where('user_id', 1);
})->get();
```

So that's for one user. For two or more users it's basically the same. You just need to chain `whereHas`s

```
$conversations = Conversation::whereHas('users', function($q){
    $q->where('user_id', 1);
})
->whereHas('users', function($q){
    $q->where('user_id', 2);
})->get();
```

Now this isn't very elegant. You can create a [query scope](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) to do all the work for you and keep the controller code clean. In `Conversation`

```
public function scopeWithUsers($query, array $userIds){
    foreach($userIds as $id){
        $query->whereHas('users', function($q) use ($id){
            $q->where('user_id', $id);
        });
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Usage:

```
$conversations = Conversation::withUsers([1,2])->get();
$conversations = Conversation::withUsers([1,2,3,4])->get();
$conversations = Conversation::withUsers([1])->get();
```

If it should only be one anyways use `first()` instead of `get()`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
class Conversation {
    public static function user_filter(Array $users) {
        $ids = array();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $ids[] = $user->id;
        }
        return self::select("conversation_id")->whereIn("user_id", $ids)->groupBy("conversation_id")->havingRaw("count(*) = " . count($ids))->get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted because you tried to translate that good old plain SQL trick... but conversations table itself has no user_id (it's in the pivot table). Close enough though, maybe only a JOIN away.

Answer (score 0):

Get all conversations with given users.

```
Conversation::whereHas('users', function($query) use ($userids) {
    $query->whereIn('user_id', $userids);
})->get();
```

If you need get special one, you can:

```
 Conversation::whereHas('users', function($query) use ($userids) {
        $query->whereIn('user_id', $userids);
    })->whereId($id)->first();
```

Comment: This won't work because it will also fetch conversations in which only one of the passed users is involved.

Comment: oh, havn't db for test it...:\